# Set the query string, but still get NullReferenceException

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to show the error message on the other page. I got the NullReferenceException, but the query string is set on the page which has error.  Would someone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
 catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace,"Error!",MessageBoxButton.OK)));

           string query=@"/ErrorPage.xaml?msg=" + ex.StackTrace.ToString() ;
           Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(query, UriKind.Relative))));
        }
```

There is the code for showing the error message when the page is loaded on other page

```
 public ErrorPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string msg = NavigationContext.QueryString["msg"].ToString();
        lstMessage.Items.Add(msg);

    }
```

Comment: check whether the StackTrace is more than 260 characters ? And try using Uri.EscapeUriString

Comment: @entropy it is 670 characters. I change the method to show the message. I store them as globle variable, so on the next page I can get it. Thank.s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should put my code into the MainPage_Load method. It works.

```
      public ErrorPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);                       
    }

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(CMSPhoneApp.App.GlobalVariables.strNofifyEmailSubject,
                        "Report Error", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            //according to the serach  it works on real devices (not on the emulator)
            //the reason the EmailComposer not pop up because can't set up an email account on the emulator
            EmailComposeTask emailcomposer = new EmailComposeTask();
            emailcomposer.To = CMSPhoneApp.App.GlobalVariables.reportAddress;
            emailcomposer.Subject = CMSPhoneApp.App.GlobalVariables.strNofifyEmailSubject;
            emailcomposer.Body = CMSPhoneApp.App.GlobalVariables.errorMsg;
            emailcomposer.Show();

        }
        else
        {
            App.GoBack();
        }
    }
```